# How can I pass in an <input> element to ng-for, which is bound to some ng-model?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

## Background

I am designing a reusable table component. The component was originally designed to merely display data in a table structure.

*e.g you pass in a data array and a columnInfo array and the component renders an HTML table*

There has been a change in requirements however, and now the table needs to support input fields.

```
Textfield 1        Textfield 2         Textfield 3         Input 1       Input 2    

testestestestestsetestsetestestsetestestsetsetsett     *dropdownhere*   *textbox here*
```

---

## The Problem

First and fore-most , simply displaying an "extra textbox column" on every row has proven difficult.

I've used a simple ng-content with single-selector

**Table Component. html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows" (click)="onCellClick(row)">

     <td *ngFor="let column of _columns">
           {{ getData(row,column) }}
     </td>

     <td><ng-content select="[test]"></ng-content></td>
</tr>
```

**Parent Component**

```
<table-component [columns] = "tableHeaders"
                 [data]="_allTasksArray"
                 (cellEvent)="getActionUrl($event)"
                 [filterAllColumns]="true"
        >

            <div  test >
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </div>

</table-component>
```

However this does not work as expected, the h1 **TEST** is only rendered in **ONE** row. And after some digging around, I discovered that the template passed in from ng-content *can only ever be displayed once*.

Not very useful for my requirements.

---

## The Question

So if there exists a way to pass in an HTML element to a component for use with ngFor,  how then can I associate these inputs with a value?

*for example* If I wanted to pass in a drop down pre-populated with values specific to each row in the table.

**This is how it should work**

```
<table-component>
    <template-for-content>
        <input [(ngModel)]="This would be linked row[column.name] in the table">
    </template-for-content>
</table-component>
```

**Table**

```
<td><ng-content someWayOfPassingDataBackToTemplate></ng-content></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the reactive forms module for angular 2, I think this would be a good use case for it. There is a good walkthrough of it in the Angular 2 docs. Reactive forms  let you define forms 'programmatically' using objects. The walkthrough shows you have to set it up so you can pass in an array of configuration objects (each object representing a single input) into a reactive-form directive and it will iterate over the array and render an input based off each configuration object. It also shows how to get the data out of a reactive form.

Comment: I've been using reactive forms, and unless i've missed something. Surely reactive forms are only for associating existing input elements with a FormControl object in the TypeScript.

My problem requires no assumption of the type of Input element, FormControl cannot create a new element , it can only be bound to an existing element in the template.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

This is the guide I was talking about. It shows you how to render inputs dynamically and how to bind them to form control objects.

Comment: Reactive forms do not answer my question, they still require me to hard-code HTML elements. I need a general-purpose method for rendering _any HTML element contained within the table's tags_